# Text fields to grow with screen size inside my div

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am implementing a website and I need to have a form, the logic behind it works and now I want it to look a bit nicer.

At the moment it looks like this:

#### Current Design

[image]

If the screen is smaller it looks really good since each text field is all the way to the right, but when I move it on my 32" monitor it looks like in the picture.
I spent the past 2 hours googling but I just can't get it to work.

So is there any way on making the text field "grow" to the right hand side when there is enough space for them?

Here is my HTML:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg font-serif text-2xl font-bold w-6/12">


            <form class="w-full max-w-lg" action="{{ route('dashboard') }}" method="post">
                @csrf
                <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 mt-3">
                    <div class="w-full md:max-w-2xl px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
                        <p class="mb-4">Stellenanzeigen erstellen:</p>
                        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2 text-base" for="titel">
                            Titel:
                        </label>
                        <input class="block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3
                        leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white @error('titel') border-red-500 @enderror" id="titel" name="titel" type="text" placeholder="Titel">
                        @error('titel')
                        <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 mt-6">
                    <div class="w-full px-3">
                        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2 text-base" for="standort">
                            Standort
                        </label>
                        <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded
                        py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white
                        focus:border-gray-500 @error('standort') border-red-500 @enderror" id="standort" name="standort" type="text" placeholder="Standort">
                        @error('standort')
                        <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
                    <div class="w-full px-3">
                        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2 text-base" for="kontakt">
                            Kontakt
                        </label>
                        <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded
                        py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white
                        focus:border-gray-500 @error('kontakt') border-red-500 @enderror" id="kontakt" name="kontakt" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                        @error('kontakt')
                        <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
                    <div class="w-full px-3">
                        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2 text-base" for="startdatum">
                            Startdatum
                        </label>
                        <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded
                        py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white
                        focus:border-gray-500 @error('startdatum') border-red-500 @enderror" id="startdatum" name="startdatum" type="date" placeholder="Startdatum">
                        @error('startdatum')
                        <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
                    <div class="w-full px-3">
                        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2 text-base" for="enddatum">
                            Enddatum
                        </label>
                        <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded
                        py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white
                        focus:border-gray-500 @error('titel') border-red-500 @enderror" id="enddatum" name="enddatum" type="date" placeholder="Enddatum">
                        @error('enddatum')
                        <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 pl-2">
                    <div class="w-full px-3">
                        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="lebenslauf">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="" name="lebenslauf" value="">
                            <span class="ml-2 text-base">Lebenslauf</span>
                        </label>

                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 pl-2">
                    <div class="w-full px-3">
                        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="anschreiben">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="" name="anschreiben" value="">
                            <span class="ml-2 text-base">Anschreiben</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 pl-2">
                    <div class="w-full px-3">
                        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="zeugnisse">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="" name="zeugnisse" value="">
                            <span class="ml-2 text-base">Zeugnisse</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 pl-4">
                    <div class="form-textarea mt-1 block w-full">
                        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2 text-base" for="beschreibung">
                            Beschreibung
                        </label>
                        <textarea class="w-full px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none @error('beschreibung') border-red-500 @enderror"
                                  name="beschreibung" id="beschreibung" rows="8" ></textarea>
                        @error('beschreibung')
                        <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-3 rounded font-medium w-full">Abschicken</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>



@endsection
```

I use Laravel and I have this one huge css sheet with 5k lines, so I won't post this :D but its the standard css sheet when importing tailwind into phpstorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the inspector to find which element is causing the issue. With the inspector you can edit the HTML and CSS without leaving the browser.

I think the issue is being caused by this line

```
        <div class="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg font-serif text-2xl font-bold w-6/12">
```

The `w-6/12` is adjusting the element to be half width.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#fluid-width